# Can moderators view votes?

Tags: discussion, moderators, votes

Can the site moderators view who casts what votes?  IE, if I upvote or downvote a post, will the mods know that it was myself and not Joe Blow de Eskimo?

Comment: No we can't.  See [Here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275052/can-moderators-see-who-upvoted-downvoted-a-specific-question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, we can't see your individual upvotes or downvotes.

We *can* see any voting trends that appear, in case you start using your votes to target other users (which is against the rules), or other users target you, but that is the extent that we can see.